# How to execute iframe tag which is coming in a variable

Tags: html, iframe

For example:
Now how can I run this code from `var v`?

The code:

```
var v = <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpxqcq6b"><iframe>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? And iframe tag is also not correct/

Comment: that should be `<iframe>` and not `<ifram>`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `innerHTML` function of Javascript to achieve this. Check below code for reference. You will need a placeholder in the document to insert the `<iframe>` element, here I've used div with `id=placeiframe`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertiFrame(){
        var v = "<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpxqcq6b'><iframe>";
        document.getElementById("placeiframe").innerHTML = v;   
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <b>Example of iFrame insertion via Javasript</b><br/>
    <input type="button" onClick="insertiFrame();" value="Insert iFrame below"/><br/>
    <div id="placeiframe"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So replace this variable value accordingly. The answer to your original query has been provided. if you are still not getting it right, you need to update the question to include the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div>
<b>Example of iFrame insertion via Javasript</b><br/>
<input type="button" onClick="insertiFrame();" value="Insert iFrame below"/>    <br/>
<div id="placeiframe"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function insertiFrame(){
    var v = "<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/wpxqcq6b'><iframe>";
    $("#placeiframe").append().html(v);
}
</script>
```